# css How to have margin on element when responsive

Tags: css

I have a simple problem I cant remember how to do

In my example I have a div that has a width and centered using margin auto.

When the window is resized I want the div to have a left and right margin when the window touches the div.

At the moment when the window is resized the div touches the edge of the window.

I want it to be this width untill the window gets to small and then it has left and right margin

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>

</div>
```

Comment: Please refer to the `@media` rules in css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .block {
        margin: 0 11px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `max-width: 90%` or whatever fixes your requirement.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media queries to control the styles of your elements.

Example:

The following example changes the background-color to lightgreen if the viewport is 480 pixels wide or wider (if the viewport is less than 480 pixels, the background-color will be pink)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

[for more](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) and 
[different device width link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/#phone-queries)

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .block {
      text-align:center;
        background: red;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 600px;
      }

      @media (max-width: 400px) {
        margin: 0 50px;
      }
      @media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
        margin: 0 30px;
      }
      @media (min-width: 801px) {
        margin: 0 10px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>repl.it</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```